# How to color just some part of a frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

A screen of what I want to do is better than explanations =>

[image: frame]

No matter how big the frame is I want to know if I can choose the color for some part of the frame

EDIT : example of what I mean, I want the top to be in blue for example even though it's the same frame (if a "slicing" can be done like strings It would be good but I don't think it exist)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import CENTER, ttk
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x200')
frame = tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,bg='red')
frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()
label = tk.Label(frame,text='test',bg='red')
label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I show the code ? I just have a label in a frame (I have defined the width and height and bg) but it's only one color I really don't know how to do that. That's why I'm asking right here

Comment: There's really no way to do it ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a `Frame` two-colored, you need to put some other widget inside to create the color stripe, for instance, another `Frame`. Then, use `place` to put the second frame inside the first one, this way you can `pack`/`grid`/`place` other widgets in your first frame without being affected by the presence of the second one.

Here is an example where the height of the color stripe is a fraction of frame's height. The stripe automatically resizes with the frame thanks to the use of the `relheight` option in `place()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class TwoColoredFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, bg1, bg2, fraction=0.5, **kw):
        kw["bg"] = bg2  # color of the lower part of the Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        # upper color stripe 
        tk.Frame(self, bg=bg1).place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=fraction)  

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x200')
frame = TwoColoredFrame(root, width=100, height=100, bg2='red', bg1="blue", fraction=0.2)
frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
label = tk.Label(frame, text='test', bg='red')
label.pack(side="bottom")

label = tk.Label(frame, text='test', bg='blue', fg="white")
label.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

If you would rather have a fixed height stripe, use instead the `height` option in `place()`:

```
class TwoColoredFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, bg1, bg2, top_height, **kw):
        kw["bg"] = bg2  # color of the lower part of the Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        tk.Frame(self, bg=bg1).place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, height=top_height)  # upper color stripe
```